# The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type [HttpWebRequest]

Tags: c#, .net, api

I have an application that does a post using

`HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);`

`http.Method = "POST";`

- More code

`Stream oRequestStream = http.GetRequestStream();`

The reciving end API on my localhost:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(HttpContext context)
{
}
```

I get the exception *The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.*

I understand that error says the media type is not supported, but HttpContext is the correct media type?

Comment: The media type is the "Content-Type" header that your client is sending with the POST. It's possible that ASP.NET APIs only accept JSON or XML by default, so you probably need to add an attribute to the method to describe what content types it accepts (and confirm what your POST is sending if you're not setting it explicitly)

Comment: Check adding to header "Content-Type" from your client

Comment: @Rup "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name=\"smime.p7m\""

Comment: OK. I haven't done this myself but [this ASP.NET forum post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/647645/how-to-accept-file-in-binary-format-in-aspnet-core.html) says you should drop the parameter from the method and instead use Request.InputStream or similar to get the posted content. I could believe that'll cancel the media type check because you're no longer asking ASP.NET to deserialize the POST, but I don't know for sure.